# Ubuntu Server: How scroll through the terminal/screen by page and line? [VirtualBox]

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, keyboard, virtualbox, shortcut-keys

Having VirtualBox with

- Hosts: Mac and Windows 10
- Guest: Ubuntu Desktop && Server (18.04) and Desktop (20.04)

In the Terminal when the screen is filled about content shown through the output after the use of many commands - I need sometimes go up and go down - I did do a research and have the following that works

**Desktop** *The Terminal is opened of course*

Mac:

- `shift` + `Fn` + `pgUp|Down` (by page)
- `shift` + `control` + `Up|Down` (by line)

Windows:

- `shift` + `pgUp|Down` (by page)
- `shift` + `Ctrl` + `Up|Down` (by line)

**Server** (direct and unique interaction with the terminal/screen itself)

The commands shown above do not work. Nothing happens for the `up|pgUp` scenarios and `~` appears for the `down|pgDown` scenarios

How accomplished the same goal for Ubuntu **Server**?

Comment: Use the `less` command to view content. Arrows and page/up work for me. I use an actual server though but would assume it does not matter it is virtual :-)

Comment: Same issue. Can't scroll the screen up to view content above the top of screen